# Compare columns of different files with different sizes and replace with NA non matching values

Tags: text-processing, text-formatting

I have three data frame:

> Dataframe 1

`chr    start   end     Id
 chr1   1       400     SN_1
 chr1   401     800     SN_2
 chr1   801     1200    SN_3
 chr1   1201    1600    SN_4
 chr1   1601    2000    SN_5
 chr1   2001    2400    SN_6
 chr1   2401    2800    SN_7`

> Dataframe 2

`chr    start   end     Id
 chr1   401     800     SN_2
 chr1   801     1200    SN_3 
 chr1   1201    1600    SN_4`

> Dataframe 3

`chr    start   end     Id
 chr1   1201    1600    SN_4
 chr1   1601    2000    SN_5
 chr1   2001    2400    SN_6`

and I would like to obtain a final data frame where, according to the 4th column of the 1st data frame, will be reported a match or a non match in relation to the 4th column of the 2nd and 3rd data frame. In a new data frame If a match is present the same Id will be reported but in case a match will be present the Id name will be replaced with an NA. Maybe just writing input and output will be easier to understand. Something Like this:

> Desirable output:

`chr    start   end     Id    Id    Id
 chr1   1       400     SN_1  NA    NA
 chr1   401     800     SN_2  SN_2  NA
 chr1   801     1200    SN_3  SN_3  NA
 chr1   1201    1600    SN_4  SN_4  SN_4
 chr1   1601    2000    SN_5  NA    SN_5
 chr1   2001    2400    SN_6  NA    SN_6
 chr1   2401    2800    SN_7  NA    NA`

I have tried with join in unix command but I cannot compare data frame of different size. Any Idea will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'FILENAME == ARGV[1] && NR>1{ df2[$2,$3,$4] }
     FILENAME == ARGV[2] && FNR>1{ df3[$2,$3,$4] }
     FILENAME == ARGV[3]{ if(FNR == 1) { printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",$0,$NF,$NF) } 
     else { printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",$0, (($2,$3,$4) in df2)? $NF :"NA",(($2,$3,$4) in df3)? $NF :"NA")} 
}' df2 df3 df1 | column -t
```

The output:

```
chr   start  end   Id    Id    Id
chr1  1      400   SN_1  NA    NA
chr1  401    800   SN_2  SN_2  NA
chr1  801    1200  SN_3  SN_3  NA
chr1  1201   1600  SN_4  SN_4  SN_4
chr1  1601   2000  SN_5  NA    SN_5
chr1  2001   2400  SN_6  NA    SN_6
chr1  2401   2800  SN_7  NA    NA
```

---

- `df2`, `df3` and `df1` are your 2nd, 3rd and 1st *dataframe* files respectively
- `FILENAME` - built-in variable pointing to the name of currently processed file
- `ARGV` - built-in variable pointing to all arguments passed to the awk script. i.e. `ARGV[1]` contains `df2`
- `FILENAME == ARGV[1] && NR>1` - encountering the 1st file (i.e. `df2`) starting from the 2nd line

  - `df2[$2,$3,$4]` - capturing crucial values from "*Dataframe 2*" as key of array `df2`
- `FILENAME == ARGV[2] && FNR>1` - encountering the 2nd file (i.e. `df3`) starting from the 2nd line

  - `df3[$2,$3,$4]` - capturing crucial values from "*Dataframe 3*" as key of array `df3`
- `FILENAME == ARGV[3]` - encountering the 3nd file (i.e. `df1`), the main *Dataframe*

Comment: funny thing: if I use the name of the flies as df1, df2 and df3 it works but if I use the name of my original files does not. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane '$,="\t";
   !@ARGV and $. == 1 and print($_, qw/Id/x2),next;
   $h{$F[1],$F[2]}->[@ARGV] = $F[3];
   !@ARGV and print $_, map { $h{$F[1],$F[2]}->[$_] // q/NA/ } 1..2;
   $. = 0 if eof;
' file3 file2 file1
```

---

### Results

```
chr    start   end     Id       Id      Id
 chr1   1       400     SN_1    NA      NA
 chr1   401     800     SN_2    SN_2    NA
 chr1   801     1200    SN_3    SN_3    NA
 chr1   1201    1600    SN_4    SN_4    SN_4
 chr1   1601    2000    SN_5    NA      SN_5
 chr1   2001    2400    SN_6    NA      SN_6
 chr1   2401    2800    SN_7    NA      NA
```

---

### Workings

- Order of inputs is: dataframe3, dataframe2, and dataframe1.
- Assuming that dataframe1 has all 4th columns filled, IOW, none missing.
- We invoke `Perl` in line-read-in+autosplit mode: `perl -lane`
- During the time 3rd frame is being read, @ARGV has 2 elements, during the 2nd frame read in it is 1 elements, and 0 during the 3rd frame.
- We populate a hash, `%h`, whose keys are the 2nd+3rd fields, `$F[1],$F[2]` and the values are anonymous array references, hence referred as: `$h{...}[...]`.
- During the time of the 1st data frame (@ARGV having 0 elements), we are printing each line with the contents of the 1st data frame, and determing whether the array elements exist or not for the 2nd/3rd frames for the corresponding current 2nd/3rd fields.